# How can I read dates in format day.month.year in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I want to read a date from the console in the format day.month.year.
For example,

```
startDate = 1.05.2016
```

and

```
secondDate = 5.05.2016
```

When I run my code and enter them I got System.FormatException. How can I read them?

```
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd.m.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd.m.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What does `m` mean? `mm`? `M`? `MM`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Also, you will want to use `TryParseExact`, in case the input is `null` or invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing days without zeros and months with zeros. Here is a pattern `d.MM.yyyy`

See [Date And Time Format In C# Programming](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1) for more reference

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you very much! Greetings, Kaloyan

Answer (score 3):

Two things;

1. You need to use [the `"d"` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-d-custom-format-specifier) instead of `dd` since your single digit days does *not* have leading zero.
2. Custom date and time specifier are case sensitive. `m` and `mm` are for minutes, but `M` and `MM` are for months.

Based on your inputs, `d.MM.yyyy` seems correct format to parse.

> I'm given a program (existing source code) that aims to count the
>   non-working days between two dates given in format day.month.year
>   (e.g. between 1.05.2015 and 15.05.2015 there are 5 non-working days –
>   Saturday and Sunday). I don't know how to read them from the console

That's easy. First of all, you need to iteration from your start date to your end date. Second, parse your current date as I told you. Then check your `DateTime`'s [`DayOfWeek` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2). If it is `Saturday` or `Sunday`, then it's a non-working day. Increase your counter by 1.

For a full example;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "d.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "d.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    Console.WriteLine($"There are {EachNonWorkingDay(startDate, endDate).Count()} non-working days");
}

private static IEnumerable<DateTime> EachNonWorkingDay(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    for (var day = fromDate.Date; day.Date <= toDate.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            yield return day;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you very much! Greetings, Kaloyan

Comment: @KaloyanK. You are welcome, added full example as well.